# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

Tags: python, mysql

Trying to store values in sql using Python Cgi script,
I have downloaded the Connector/Python for MySQL successfully. I used the following code in Python's shell to test my connection:

```
import mysql.connector
```

I received the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

when trying to import MySQL.connector.

Comment: What exact mysql package did you install. What is the name of it? Did you check the documentation for the package you installed to know what you are supposed to use to import it?

Comment: Please be more specific. I don't understand what you are referring to by "the community instr".

Comment: Not enough details.

Answer (score 10):

Just try this command:

> pip install mysql-connector-python-rf

then try your command again, it'll run correctly.

Comment: What is the difference to "pip install mysql-connector"?

Comment: you can find answer here https://github.com/pypi/warehouse/issues/5537

Answer (score 8):

try below command

> pip install mysql-connector

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html claims that one should install `mysql-connector-python` Also https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector/ describes itself as deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem that was created by conflicting package names.

Try creating a fresh virtual environment, then running `pip install mysql-connector-python`.